# Build UI form that is operate POST / GET operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, rest

I've very good back-end development skills (especially in Java and .net) and I'm doing very well in exposing REST services. 
The issue is that once I want to build simple form (3-4 fields) or web page that will access and operate these services it takes me long time to build the HTML and connect it using jQuery or Angular to the server side.
I would like to know if there is simple tool to build such forms and link them to the services without writing bunch of js code.

Thank you
Moshe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad to answer. I will let you know the workflow I used in my initial days as a front end developer.

1. A drag and drop [builder](http://bootsnipp.com/forms) to build my HTML form
2. A validation [plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate
3. A plugin to [convert form data](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) to JSON format for submitting to the REST API

these are good starting points as it removes a lot of hand coding. Suitable for simple forms but as you start building more complex forms you should start evolving to better solutions that will suit you.

Comment: Thank you. I still missing simple way to bind data from JSON to the form or from the form

Comment: these plugins will come in handy                                    http://jquerymy.com/
http://gwendall.github.io/way/

http://gdb.thewebdev.guru/examples/